# How can compressed archives like .RAR be repaired?

Tags: compression, zip, 7-zip, rar, winrar

I'm interested to know how WinRAR and 7-zip repairs archives but unfortunately I couldn't find any description about this process.
So I'm here to ask: How does WinRAR or 7-zip repairing process work? and which part of archive (File's header, contents and etc) can be repaired using this process? What does "Repairing rate" exactly means?

Comment: there are many differant kinds of recovery possible, depending on the compression algorthm and its implementation, the options selected when creating the archive, etc. Different approaches to recovery address different types of damage to the archive array, and the degree of overhead the user is willing to deal with. For instance PAR files are the most versatile recovery mechanism (they can deal with huge damage if there are enough of them) but they take space, and time to generate. Either way, there is no single clear answer to this question.

Comment: Have you read the WinRAR manual, especially the section titled "Protecting archives from damage"?

Answer (score 1):

A `rar` file has `Recovery Records`, so in case of damaged files parts of it can be recovered. When you create a `rar`, you can specify an amount of correction data in percent to be used. I found that on the German Wikipedia only (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAR_%28Dateiformat%29#Recovery_Records), the English version lacks this.